# my code regarding the simple String display is not showing the required output?

Tags: java

```
public class Zoo
{
    public String coolMethod(){
        return "wow !! baby..";
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Zoo z=new Zoo();
        z.coolMethod();
    }
}
```

This is a simple code  to display a string but it is not showing the desired output i.e. in this case string "wow !! baby.." .It is compiling and executing fine but not showing the result.

Comment: You return the string but don't output it

Comment: Try to print the returned value from the `coolMethod` and I bet it will show you something.

Comment: Please go through some tutorial or notes about methods in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st way

```
public class Zoo
{
    public String coolMethod(){
        return "wow !! baby..";
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Zoo z=new Zoo();
       System.out.println(z.coolMethod()) ;
    }
}
```

2nd way

```
    public class Zoo
    {
        public void coolMethod(){
            System.out.println( "wow !! baby..");
        }
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Zoo z=new Zoo();
            z.coolMethod();


  }
}
```

In your `coolMethod()` method the return type is `String`. In order to display the result of this method, you have to return it `void` or use `System.out.print();`
.
For your second problem is, you do not have main method inside your class.Create a new  class Test then put this method

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
Moo m = new Moo();
m.useMyCoolMethod();
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

The method `coolMethod()` just returns the String. But looks like you forgot to put the code to print the string. You may do like this

```
System.out.println(z.coolMethod());
```

Comment: thank you sanbhat !! that was so silly of me .. excuse me i am just a beginner.

Comment: public class Zoo
{
public  static String coolMethod(){
return "wow !! baby..";
}
}
class Moo extends Zoo{
public void useMyCoolMethod(){
System.out.println("Moo says. "+ this.coolMethod());
Zoo z=new Zoo();
System.out.println("zoo says " +z.coolMethod());
}
}
 now can someone tell me why this code is showing exception in thread main no such method error. and how to fix it

Comment: @gjman2
here is the code
'public class Zoo { 
public static String coolMethod(){
 return "wow !! baby..";
 }
 } 
class Moo extends Zoo{
 public void useMyCoolMethod(){
 System.out.println("Moo says. "+ this.coolMethod());
 Zoo z=new Zoo();
 System.out.println("zoo says " +z.coolMethod());
 }
 }'

Comment: I have the answer check it out

Comment: Have you check the answer? @user2545332

Comment: @user2545332 it will be appropriate to either edit your post.. or ask a new question instead of pasting the code as comments..

Answer (score 1):

You specified coolMethod() to return, not to print. There won't be any printed output. You also did not assign a string variable to z.coolMethod() nor wrap print around it so your desired output is lost.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Zoo
 {
  public String coolMethod(){
    return "wow !! baby.."; // return String
  }
 public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Zoo z=new Zoo();
    z.coolMethod(); //here you are getting "wow !! baby..", but you are not printing it.
 }
}
```

replace

```
 z.coolMethod(); with System.out.println(z.coolMethod()); // now you will see the out put in console
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to produce some output to your console, use System.out.print() method. For example:

System.out.print("fff");
System.out.print("ggggg");

will produce fffggggg. 
If you want to print the same result in separate line, use System.out.println. For example:

System.out.println("fff");
System.out.println("ggggg");

will produce 
fff 
ggggg